# BASH SCRIPT, Remove a char from awk variables

Tags: shell, variables, awk

I'm trying to remove specific chars from `awk` string but I'm having problems with regex.

How can I make something like this?

```
A = "123 456"
```

output:

```
12 56
```

I tried:

```
echo $A | awk -F '[[:space:]]' '{print $($($1)::-1" "),$($($2 -1::))}'
```

Some one know the correct form to use theese regex?

Comment: if you want to operate digits then `bash` only can achive the results. `x='123 456'`  and `echo ${x/[0-9] [0-9]/ }`

Comment: What does that title even mean? What are you trying to achieve? Remove specific chars `3` and `4`? or chars around space?

Comment: sorry, but what do you really do with your `$($($...`. It seems you try to extract sub part from field but using enhanced regex. Do you want to remove 1 char around the separation field ? you write *specific* char, which one, in don't see specific, just relative one, ...

Comment: "Use these regex" -- use *what* regex? There is no regex in your question. (There's a mess of invalid syntax, but it looks nothing like any POSIX regex syntax, and how's anyone supposed to know how to interpret it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Awk`

```
$ echo 123 456 | awk 'sub(/. ./," ")'
12 56

$ awk 'sub(/. ./," ")' <<<"123 456"
12 56

$ A="123 456"
$ echo "$A" | awk 'sub(/. ./," ")'
12 56
```

Comment: ...though there's hardly any need for `awk` for that. `echo "${A/? ?/ }"` does the same thing with built-in functionality only.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : true, since there was `awk` tag in question, I posted solution in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use bash because bash script

```
$ echo ${A/? ?/ }
12 56
```